# Android browser scaling?

Tags: android, browser, mobile, webkit

I'm trying to create a mobile website for android. When I set the width of the body to 480px (the width of the screen) the result is about 50% larger than what I expect. It seems that android is scaling what it draws and messing up all my layouts. Does anyone know how to disable this, or work around it?

I'm already using this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing the secret new Android-only viewport property "[target-densityDpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796814/how-do-i-get-the-wvga-android-browser-to-stop-scaling-my-images/2799580)" which you can use to configure browser scaling.  See the linked question for more details.

Comment: target-densitydpi is being depreciated, and no longer works in Chrome for Android. DIscussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592015/support-for-target-densitydpi-is-removed-from-webkit

Answer (score 2):

A device running Android does not necessarily have a screen width of 480 Pixel. Don't set a fixed width at all.

Comment: I'm testing it on my droid, which does, and it reports it as 320 if I alert document width, no matter what I set the viewport width to.