# How do I get the WVGA Android browser to stop scaling my images?

Tags: android, browser, webkit, highdpi

I'm designing an HTML page for display in Android browsers.  Consider this simple example page:

```
<html>
<head><title>Simple!</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks just fine on the standard HVGA phones (320x480), but on HDPI WVGA sizes (480x800 or 480x854) the built-in browser automatically scales the image up; it looks ugly.

I've read that I should be able to use this tag to force the browser to stop scaling my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

... but all that does is disable user scaling (the zoom buttons disappear); it doesn't actually prevent the browser from scaling my image.  Adjusting the scale factors (setting them all to 2.0 or 0.5) has no effect at all.

How can I force the WVGA browser to stop scaling my images?

Comment: I've noticed that configuring the "Default Zoom" setting in the browser's settings to "Far" will disable image scaling, but I can't expect all of my users to do this.

Comment: There's an API to set "Default Zoom" added in Android 2.1 / API level 7. webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom()

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I'm building a web site, not an Android app with a WebView, so I can't use the Android API.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ah, found it by searching through the Android source code.  There's a new Android-specific "[target-densityDpi](https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/webkit.git;a=commit;h=f10585d69aaccf4c1b021df143ee0f08e338cf31)" setting available in the "viewport" meta tag; as far as I can tell, it's totally undocumented, except for the check-in comment!

> Add dpi support for WebView.
>
> In the "viewport" meta tag, you can specify "target-densityDpi".
>   If it is not specified, it uses the default, 160dpi as of today.
>   Then the 1.0 scale factor specified in the viewport tag means 100%
>   on G1 and 150% on Sholes. If you set "target-densityDpi" to
>   "device-dpi", then the 1.0 scale factor means 100% on both G1 and Sholes.
>
> Implemented Safari's window.devicePixelRatio and css media query
>   device-pixel-ratio.
>
> So if you use "device-dpi" and modify the css for font-size and image
>   src depending on window.devicePixelRatio, you can get a better page on
>   Sholes/Passion.
>
> Here is a list of options for "target-densityDpi".
>
> device-dpi:    Use the device's native dpi as target dpi.
>   low-dpi:       120dpi
>   medium-dpi:    160dpi, which is also the default as of today
>   high-dpi:      240dpi
>   :      We take any number between 70 and 400 as a valid target dpi.

Comment: Support for target-densityDpi was added to Android Source on 21 Sep 2009 and doesn't seem to have been included in Android 1.6 at least. It was added in this commit: https://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/webkit.git;a=commit;h=f10585d69aaccf4c1b021df143ee0f08e338cf31

Comment: @morganchristiansson That's true, but there are very few Android 1.6 HDPI devices in the wild.  LG has a couple of phones that fit that profile...  Those people will probably have a bad experience.

Comment: I'm targeting LDPI/small devices such as HTC Tattoo and SE X10 Mini which sadly are both Android 1.6.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but the docs are not capitalizing any of it - it's target-densitydpi not target-densityDpi as in <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 5):

It's now part of the API documentation for the WebView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

See the section entitled **Building web pages to support different screen densities**