# Android initial scale - PHP

Tags: android, iphone, meta-tags

In iPhone, there are php scripts that control the initial scale and max scale of website viewing that are like these:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=3.0;">
```

Would there be similar functions that work for android? Thanksalot.

Comment: That's not a PHP script, PHP does not run natively on either platform (not without rooting it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the answer to your question already exists. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673436/android-browser-scaling)

> "You're missing the secret new Android-only viewport property '[target-densityDpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796814/how-do-i-get-the-wvga-android-browser-to-stop-scaling-my-images/2799580)' which you can use to configure browser scaling. See the linked question for more details."

Comment: if I apply <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">, would that be better? and would it be other secrets that can control the min and max scale? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently. Give it a try! This solution received many upvotes so I would imagine it's trustworthy. Please try it and let me know if it works because I'm gonna use it too then.